# AndroidX migration issue

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio-3.0

In Android studio there is option for the migration, in case of the xml it's not working fine, Constraint layout migrated to 
    androidx.constraintlayout.ConstraintLayout
but it should be
    androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

Many other issues while migration

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use the latest version in `build.gradle` file:

```
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```

And define the `ConstraintLayout` in the XML files as:

```
      <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
       ...
       />
```

Unfortunately the android jetpack tool is not working as good as it should and you have to modify some code manually.

Comment: It was the same for me as well. If you're not comfortable with it just revert it back using your backup.
There's no other way to refactor automatically rather than using the jetpack tool.

Answer (score 0):

AndroidX is part of the new components for development created by Google, but one of the missing steps is this, make sure you have

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

In gradle.properties

in your gradle app level, please verify you have this:

```
//Android
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```